# Cannot access to dashboard on localhost

Tags: urls, dashboard

while i am trying to migrate my WP website from to localhost, i changed the Host Name from Dashboard -->> Settings (WordPress/localhost ---> exp.00webhost.com)

Now i want to access my website on localhost using the Dashboard 
when i connect to website i get this [image: localhost]
but when i tried to access another page i got the URL of 000webhost
[image: access to another page]
.
Any idea on how to change this URL,while i have not the access to the dashboard

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was wp_options by updating the website URL.
This query is helpful

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='YOUR_SITE_URL' WHERE option_name='siteurl'
```